# What does the following statement on nginx config mean?

Tags: linux, nginx, php, php-fpm

I am seeing a statement on nginx config but can't figure out what it does. 
this works when I am at the main directory under path; however, when I try to access files in subdirectories, it doesn't work. What does this mean and how would I change it to fix the issue with accessing subdirectories?

```
if (!-e $request_filename) { rewrite ^ /path/index.php last; }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this checks whether there is a file, directory, or symbolic link that matches the `$request_filename`. If such a file is not found, the connection is being redirected to `/path/index.php`.

Statements like these are normally used to allow url rewriting (pretty URLS) and serving of static files.